# Real Analysis Question related to weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sin(1/x) & x \ne 0 \\ 
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
 Prove that for any   $\epsilon>0 $ there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $$\int_0^1 |f(x) - p(x)| \, dx \lt \epsilon.$$

Comment: What is epsilon, what is p(x), what have you done so far, what's your effort and/or insights...??

Comment: Oh, and write mathematics in this site with using LaTeX, otherwise it's easy to misunderstand what you write.

Comment: trigometric polynomial?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Weierstrass approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)?

Comment: the Weierstrass Approx. Thrm. says "Let I be a closed bounded interval and f:I-->R is continuous then for each positive epsilon there is a polynomial p:R-->R such that |f(x)−p(x)|<ϵ for all points x in I"

Comment: @lola: Do you know your interval?

Comment: Is your function continuous?

Comment: the function is continuous

Comment: @lola: Note that, in your problem, they use a different norm while in Weierstrass theorem they use the infinite norm $||\cdot||_{\infty}$.

Comment: @lola: Your function is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @lola: Your function is integrable and it is a well known fact that every integrable function can be [approximated](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195070/prove-integral-metric-is-separable) by a continuous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Everything happens on $[0,1]$ and the function $f$ is continuous except at $0$ hence one can consider the functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f_n(x)=f(x)$ if $x\geqslant1/n$ and $f_n(x)=f(1/n)$ if $x\leqslant1/n$. These are continuous hence Weierstrass gives some polynomials $p_n$ such that $\|f_n-p_n\|_\infty\leqslant1/n$.

Can you estimate $\int\limits_0^1|f-p_n|$? You might want to decompose the integral into $\int\limits_0^{1/n}+\int\limits_{1/n}^1$ and to bound each part separately...

Comment: This is a very nice answer, as usual.  I especially like the fact that it seems not to use any unnecessary tools, so it should be useful to the broadest possible audience.